# Sweep out something from under the couch?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Let's say there's something under the couch and you use a broom to get it.

Is it right to say:

> You *swept it out (from) under the couch?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's *grammatically* correct but from what I've read, you should try to avoid redundant prepositions in formal writing. This is the sort of thing that most people wouldn't notice.

Source: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/prepositions/

Press CTRL + F then search for "up over the fence."

Answer (score 1):

You can either say

*You swept it from under the couch*

or

*You swept it out from under the couch*

They way you have put parentheses around *from*, suggests you believe this is optional, but that does not work (for me at least).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the tense, you can say it how you did (past-tense) but if it is in present-tense then you would say...

"You sweep it out from under the couch." or "You sweep it from under the couch."

Like how a game tells you what you did in the present tense (e.g. "You take the ball.")